# How can selection be disabled in PDFView?

Tags: ios, swift, pdfkit, pdfview

Displaying a `PDFDocument` in a `PDFView` allows the user to select parts of the document and perform actions e.g. "copy" with the selection.
How can selection be disabled in a PDFView while preserving the possibility for the user to zoom in and out and scroll in the PDF?

`PDFView` itself does not seem to offer such a property nor does the `PDFViewDelegate`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to subclass PDFView, as such:

```
class MyPDFView: PDFView {

    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func addGestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if gestureRecognizer is UILongPressGestureRecognizer {
            gestureRecognizer.isEnabled = false
        }

        super.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just need to do is it will auto clear the selection and User will no longer long-press on PDF text.

```
class MyPDFView: PDFView {

    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        self.currentSelection = nil
        self.clearSelection()

        return false
    }

    override func addGestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if gestureRecognizer is UILongPressGestureRecognizer {
            gestureRecognizer.isEnabled = false
        }

        super.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }

}
```

This below 2 lines need to add in canPerformAction()

```
self.currentSelection = nil
self.clearSelection()
```

Answer (score 3):

For iOS 13, the above solution no longer works. It looks like they've changed the internal implementation of `PDFView` and specifically how the gesture recognizers are set up. I think generally it's discouraged to do this kind of thing, but it can still be done without using any internal API, here's how:

1) Recursively gather all subviews of `PDFView` (see below for the helper function to do this)

```
let allSubviews = pdfView.allSubViewsOf(type: UIView.self)
```

2) Iterate over them and deactivate any `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`s:

```
for gestureRec in allSubviews.compactMap({ $0.gestureRecognizers }).flatMap({ $0 }) {
    if gestureRec is UILongPressGestureRecognizer {
        gestureRec.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Helper func to recursively get all subviews of a given type:

```
func allSubViewsOf<T: UIView>(type: T.Type) -> [T] {
    var all: [T] = []
    func getSubview(view: UIView) {
        if let aView = view as? T {
            all.append(aView)
        }
        guard view.subviews.count > 0 else { return }
        view.subviews.forEach{ getSubview(view: $0) }
    }
    getSubview(view: self)
    return all
}
```

I'm calling the above code from the `viewDidLoad` method of the containing view controller.

I haven't yet found a good way to work this into a subclass of `PDFView`, which would be the preferred way for reusability and could just be an addition to the above `NonSelectablePDFView`. What I've tried so far is overriding `didAddSubview` and adding the above code after the call to `super`, but that didn't work as expected. It seems like the gesture recognizers are only being added at a later step, so figuring out when that is and if there's a way for the subclass to call some custom code after this happened would be a next step here.

Comment: This disables the long press edit but not the double tap and hold. Add: type(of: gestureRec).description() == "UITapAndAHalfRecognizer" to the if in 2) above.

Answer (score 1):

With Swift 5 and iOS 12.3, you can solve your problem by overriding [`addGestureRecognizer(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622496-addgesturerecognizer) method and [`canPerformAction(_:withSender:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621105-canperformaction) method in a `PDFView` subclass.

```
import UIKit
import PDFKit

class NonSelectablePDFView: PDFView {

    override func addGestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        (gestureRecognizer as? UILongPressGestureRecognizer)?.isEnabled = false
        super.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }

    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

}
```

---

As an alternative to the previous implementation, you can simply toggle `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` `isEnabled` property to `false` in the initializer.

```
import UIKit
import PDFKit

class NonSelectablePDFView: PDFView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        if let gestureRecognizers = gestureRecognizers {
            for gestureRecognizer in gestureRecognizers where gestureRecognizer is UILongPressGestureRecognizer {
                gestureRecognizer.isEnabled = false
            }
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

}
```

Comment: it looks like this answer is not working anymore in iOS13, Apple did change something even with this code is still selected text ! , on iOS12 and below it was working fine !

Answer (score 1):

You should note that this is not sufficient to disable text selecting, as there is a UITapAndHalfRecognizer as well – obviously a private Apple class - that also creates selections.

It is attached to the PDFDocumentView, which is another private implementation detail of PDFView, and which you can not replace with your own class implementation.

Answer (score 1):

In my test, double tap and "tap then drag" won't enable selection on iOS16, but for iOS13 it will, so here goes:

1. Extend `UIViewController`, add a function to disable text selection. I'm throwing it in `UIViewController`'s extension so when calling it, I don't need to call `pdfView. recursivelyDisableSelection(view: pdfView)`, just `recursivelyDisableSelection(view: pdfView)` would seem a little better.

```swift
import UIKit
import PDFKit
extension UIViewController {

    func recursivelyDisableSelection(view: UIView) {
        
        // Get all recognizers for the PDFView's subviews. Here we are ignoring the recognizers for the PDFView itself, since we know from testing that not the reason for the mess.
        for rec in view.subviews.compactMap({$0.gestureRecognizers}).flatMap({$0}) {
            // UITapAndAHalfRecognizer is for a gesture like "tap first, then tap again and drag", this gesture also enable's text selection
            if rec is UILongPressGestureRecognizer || type(of: rec).description() == "UITapAndAHalfRecognizer" {
                rec.isEnabled = false
            }
        }
        
        // For all subviews, if they do have subview in itself, disable the above 2 gestures as well.
        for view in view.subviews {
            if !view.subviews.isEmpty {
                recursivelyDisableSelection(view: view)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. When calling the function, pass the instance of `PDFView` you wanna disable text selection. Notice: it should be called AFTER PDFView's document is set, otherwise it won't work.
3. Warning: If you enabled [usePageViewController()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfview/2877501-usepageviewcontroller) for your PDFView, it seems when scrolling to change current page, gestures will be added again. A reasonable thought would be adding an observer for `PDFViewPageChanged` message, I tried, it only works sometimes. A better notification message to listen to is `PDFViewVisiblePagesChanged`, this way it always works. Again, observer should be added after PDFView's document has been set otherwise it won't work.

So if you are using pageViewController like me, you should call this in 2 places: One after whenever document is set, this disable selection for the first PDFPage, another in `PDFViewVisiblePagesChanged` notification, for following page scrolling.

```swift
pdfView.document = `YOUR_PDF_DOCUMENT`
recursivelyDisableSelection(view: pdfView)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(pageChanged), name: .PDFViewVisiblePagesChanged, object: nil)
```

Later in your view controller, define the objective c wrapper function:

```
@objc func pageChanged() {
    recursivelyDisableSelection(view: pdfView)
}
```